# Discrete math: Simplified the following english sentence?

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics, logic

Simplified the following english sentence?

It is not the case that overnight lows are not in the 60s or the furnace is running.

What I tried is ignore the exactly meaning in the real life. So I took

l: overnight lows are not in the 60s

r: furnace is running.

and then I got this expression: ¬(l∨r) $\equiv $ ¬$(\overline{\overline{l\vee q}})$
                                       $\equiv$ ¬ $(\overline{\overline{l}\wedge \overline{q}})$   $\equiv$  ${\overline{l}\wedge \overline{q}}$
....and I found it just back to the same expression. I so confusing how to know whether it is the simplest one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and then I got this expression ... $\bar l \land \bar q$

Correct. All that's left is to translate it back into plain language.

- $\bar l$ = overnight lows *are* in the 60s
- $\bar q$ = the furnace is not running

So, in the end: `overnight lows are in the 60s and the furnace is not running`.